# android SQL DB Helper

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-activity, android-sqlite

Firstly, please be patient with me as i'm still a novice with android and java.

I am developing an android application using an SQLite Database and i am currently following a tutorial to create a login system using SQLite.

the tutorial is here: 
http://techblogon.com/android-login-registration-screen-with-sqlite-database-example/

my question is, in this tutorial the author creates a loginDataBaseAdapter for the login activity, will i have to make a specific adapter for each activity that uses the Database or just one if i were to add more activities in?

for example, i want my app to have 3 tables

User: userID, username, Password and Email
Product: productID, productname, product description,product price
Customer: customerID, customername, address, phonenumber, emailadress

would i then have to create helpers like; userDatabaseHelper, ProductDataBaseHelper, CustomerDataBaseHelper?

Any answers would be greatly appreciated and if i'm going about this the completely wrong way, some direction would also be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Yes... unless you use some kind of ORM library. Take a look at cupboard:
https://bitbucket.org/qbusict/cupboard

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own "DAL" (Data access layer) for each table or logic you have. In your case, you 3 tables are related between them and then probably one DAL is enough.
For example, you can create a file called "DataAccess.java" and include here a class which handle all your requirements.
From my point of view, that class should be able to handle all your CRUD operations by exposing to higher levels only an interface.
Inside that class you can separate the responsibility of each table per different classes referenced - But isn't required since your tables are related and then related operations (like adding an entire customer) could be problematic if each chunk has it own responsibility.
I hope this answer is useful, otherwise I will be happy to elaborate.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i ended up going for seperate adapter classes and one dbhelper class. for what i needed this was fine.